# Adding previous row with current row using Window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe where, I want to calculate a running total based on current row Amount value and Previous row sum of Amount value based on groupid and id. Let me put out the df

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import pandas as pd


 sc = spark.sparkContext
data1 = {'date': {0: '2018-04-03', 1: '2018-04-04', 2: '2018-04-05', 3: '2018-04-06', 4: '2018-04-07'},
         'id': {0: 'id1', 1: 'id2', 2: 'id1', 3: 'id3', 4: 'id2'},
         'group': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '2', 4: '1'},
         'amount': {0: 50, 1: 40, 2: 50, 3: 55, 4: 20}}
df1_pd = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=data1.keys())

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1_pd)
df1.show()


+----------+---+-----+------+
|      date| id|group|amount|
+----------+---+-----+------+
|2018-04-03|id1|    1|    50|
|2018-04-04|id2|    1|    40|
|2018-04-05|id1|    1|    50|
|2018-04-06|id3|    2|    55|
|2018-04-07|id2|    1|    20|
+----------+---+-----+------+
```

the out put I am looking for

```
+----------+---+-----+------+---+
|      date| id|group|amount|sum|
+----------+---+-----+------+---+
|2018-04-03|id1|    1|    50|50 |
|2018-04-04|id2|    1|    40|90 |
|2018-04-05|id1|    1|    50|140|
|2018-04-06|id3|    2|    55|55 |
|2018-04-07|id2|    1|    20|160|
+----------+---+-----+------+---+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Window definition:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

w = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(
    Window.unboundedPreceding,  # Take all rows from the beginning of frame
    Window.currentRow           # To current row
)
```

Sum:

```py
(df1.withColumn("sum", sum("amount").over(w))
    .orderBy("date")   # Sort for easy inspection. Not necessary
    .show())
```

Result:

```
+----------+---+-----+------+---+      
|      date| id|group|amount|sum|
+----------+---+-----+------+---+
|2018-04-03|id1|    1|    50| 50|
|2018-04-04|id2|    1|    40| 90|
|2018-04-05|id1|    1|    50|140|
|2018-04-06|id3|    2|    55| 55|
|2018-04-07|id2|    1|    20|160|
+----------+---+-----+------+---+
```

Comment: is there a equivalent function for "unboundedPreceding" in scala?

Comment: "unboundedPreceding"  is only available from spark 2.1, I am using spark 2.0.1