# Is there any way I can do the same thing to dataframe as mapPartitions to rdd in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to apply a function to the dataframe. The function will return the mean of the number of this row and the row before it, so as the existing of the lookback, the rows number of the final results will not the same as the original dataframe. For now I use mapPartition to do that. But is it possible that I can return the same thing but directly do the calculation on the dataframe itself, don't need to transfer it back to the rdd.

```
original dataframe:
+-----+-------+---+---+
|group|row_num|cnt|val|
+-----+-------+---+---+
|    1|      1|  4|  1|
|    1|      2|  4|  2|
|    1|      3|  4|  3|
|    1|      4|  4|  4|
|    2|      1|  4|  5|
|    2|      2|  4|  6|
|    2|      3|  4|  7|
|    2|      4|  4|  8|
+-----+-------+---+---+

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def mean(rows):
    res = []
    val = []
    row_num = []
    for row in rows:
        print row.val
        if row.row_num == 1:
            val = []
            row_num = []
        val.append(row.val)
        row_num.append(row.row_num)
        if row.row_num == row.cnt:
            results = cal(val)
            #print results
            index = -1
            for item in results[::-1]:
                res.append((row.group, row_num[index], item))
                index = index - 1
    return res

def cal(val):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, len(val)):
        res.append((val[i] + val[i - 1]) / 2)
    return res


sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 1, 4, 1), (1, 2, 4, 2), (1, 3, 4, 3), (1, 4, 4, 4),
                      (2, 1, 4, 5), (2, 2, 4, 6), (2, 3, 4, 7), (2, 4, 4, 8)])
scheme = StructType([
    StructField("group", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("row_num", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("cnt", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("val", IntegerType(), False)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, scheme)
df = df.repartition("group")

rdd_new = df.rdd.mapPartitions(mean)
scheme_new = StructType([
    StructField("group", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("row_num", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("mean", IntegerType(), False)
])
df_new = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_new, scheme_new)
df_new.show()

the output I want:
+-----+-------+----+
|group|row_num|mean|
+-----+-------+----+
|    1|      4|   3|
|    1|      3|   2|
|    1|      2|   1|
|    2|      4|   7|
|    2|      3|   6|
|    2|      2|   5|
+-----+-------+----+
```

Comment: Have you explored window functions? https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html gives you a good walkthrough of how to use them.

Also, take a look at this question for more detail for a related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144313/adding-previous-row-with-current-row-using-window-function

Comment: @Nanda Hello, Nanda, I checked the two links about window functions. Yeah, window functions is a way of thinking to solve the question. But as here I only post a simple calculation of calculate the mean, but my real calculations is a complex which calculated a lot of market indicators. So is it possible to use the window functions to express my calculation functions? And the user-defined window functions seems does not supported by PyPpark?

Comment: I have run into some limitation with the window functions on pyspark as well. I can't really answer your questions without knowing which functions you'll be needing.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Got that, thank you very much for your help :)